# SSD in early 2008 Xserve Apple Drive Module

Tags: ssd, sata, sas, xserve

Pretty much the title: it possible to use a modern, 2.5″ SSD in an Apple Drive Module on a early 2008 Xserve? This would be replacing a 15k RPM SAS drive, and in most places I've looked that HDD is almost as expensive than a similarly sized SSD.

Comment: Well, for me these SSDs is recognized in standard SATA caddy:
Western Digital SiliconEdge Blue SSD - 64GB SATA-II
OCZ Vertex 2 SSD 128GB SATA-II

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSD drives behave exactly like standard disks, so the only thing you should care about is the drive's interface. If a SSD drive has a SAS interface, it can be conneted to any SAS disk controller, regardless of the surrounding hardware and operating system.

Comment: While this is true physically and electrically, there may be logical reasons why this doesn't work, such as the controller firmware requiring specific drive models or specially keyed firmware on the drives.  I can't say I've ever seen this in practice, but I've seen anecdotes to this effect. That said, it'll probably be fine

Answer (score -3):

Unless you can make the ssd run at 1.5 Gbps it will not be recognized.

I tried this on early 2008 Xserve and the flash was not recognized.

Same thing with a newer SATA hard drive, but you can jumper 5-6 on the SATA hard drive to make it run at 1.5Gbps (instead of 3 or 6 Gbps)

Comment: If you're going to make jumper recommendations can you detail the exact make and model as jumper setting vary wildly between these.